"Sign in with Apple" repeatedly requesting for account access unexpectedly
I’m setting up Sign in with Apple ID in my web app and the signup process is running smoothly.
Users are redirected to the Apple login page, where they grant permission to share their email and name, followed by a callback.
However, a problem occurs with users who are already registered. as the process should simply verify their credentials without asking for additional permissions, since the app is already authorized to access their email and name but they are being asked again for these permissions after logging in, suggesting they are creating the account in the app again.
How can I indicate in the authorization request that a user has already been authorized so that the permissions screen doesn’t reappear every single time?
Other providers handle this by adding the parameter prompt=none to the request.
An example of my request is https://mycompany.apple.com/auth/authorize?state=myRedactedState&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code&client_id=com.mycompany.client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycompany.company.org%2Fv1%2Fauth&scope=name%20email
